# How to traverse a nested loop and get values in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a loop where I want to get a territory and list of items in that territory, but I am always getting null on the items

How my entity dataset comes after doing a select

```
 PricingRuleEntity(territory=Maryland, items=[PromoItem(itemCode=Nivea Men Box (12.0 PC), name=5e0648a9e5, uom=null), PromoItem(itemCode=Dove Men Box (6.0 Box), name=d805f9bb9d, uom=null)])]
```

Here is my loop

```
 List<Territory> territories = new ArrayList<>();
            for(PricingRuleEntity pricingRuleEntity: pricing){
                Territory territory = new Territory();
                territory.setTerritory(pricingRuleEntity.getTerritory());
                territory.setListItems(pricingRuleEntity.getItems());
                for(Territory itemCode: territories) {
                    PromoItem itemCode1 = new PromoItem();
                    itemCode1.setItemCode(String.valueOf(itemCode1.getItemCode()));
                    territories.add(itemCode);
                }

                territories.add(territory);
            }

            System.out.println(territories);
```

My Entities
Pricing Rule Entity

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "pricing_rule")
public class PricingRuleEntity extends BaseEntity {
   
    @Column(name = "territory", nullable = false)
    private String territory;

    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "JSON")
    public List<PromoItem> items;
}
```

Territory Entity

```
@Data
public class Territory {
    @JsonProperty("territory")
    String territory;
    @JsonProperty("listItems")
    List<PromoItem> listItems;

}
```

PromoItem Entity

```
@Data
public class PromoItem {
    @JsonProperty("item_code")
    String itemCode;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    String name;
    @JsonProperty("uom")
    Integer uom;
}
```

the first loop results

```
itemCode: Territory(territory=Maryland, listItems=[PromoItem(itemCode=Nivea Men Box (12.0 PC), name=5e0648a9e5, uom=null), PromoItem(itemCode=Zesta Jam Box (5.0 pcs), name=d805f9bb9d, uom=null)])
```

I have managed to extract the territory, but whenever I try to access the PromoItem items I end up getting them as null and also the item code as null.

```
 itemCode1: PromoItem(itemCode=null, name=null, uom=null)
```

What am I doing wrong. Any help towards the right direction is welcomed

**Edit 1:**
AS guided on the comments section by @ScaryWombat changed I

`itemCode1.setItemCode(String.valueOf(itemCode1.getItemCode()));`

to

`itemCode1.setItemCode(String.valueOf(itemCode.getListItems()));`,

the result is

`PromoItem(itemCode=[PromoItem(itemCode=Nivea Men Box (12.0 PC), name=5e0648a9e5, uom=null), PromoItem(itemCode=Zesta Jam Box (5.0 pcs), name=d805f9bb9d, uom=null)], name=null, uom=null)`.

How can I get

`(Nivea Men Box (12.0 PC), Zesta Jam Box (5.0 pcs))`

from my implementation

Comment: why would you do `itemCode1.setItemCode(String.valueOf(itemCode1.getItemCode()));` ?  It is the same object!

Comment: Hi @ScaryWombat,oh my bad, fixed it but am getting `[PromoItem(itemCode=Nivea Men Box (12.0 PC), name=5e0648a9e5, uom=null), PromoItem(itemCode=Zesta Jam Box (5.0 pcs), name=d805f9bb9d, uom=null)]' I just want the Itemcode only

Comment: You also try to add the same item that you have on the iterator back to the list `territories.add(itemCode);`. Did you mean to add it to another list?

Comment: @sorifiend yes I want to add to the same list,  so that I have a list that has a territory and itemcodes under it